# jquery resize div height relative to document height

Tags: jquery, magento

I am trying to dynamically resize a div using jquery so that it adjusts to the height of the visitor's viewport within Magento.

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(window).load(function() {
$j(".header-clear").css({'height':(($j(document).height())/2.7)+'px'});
});
```

For example if the visitor's viewport is 1080px then the div height should be set to 400px.

**EDIT:** Changed script based on answers and .jquery api for .resize and .height, and removed live link.

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(window).load(function() {
$j(".header-clear").css({'height': parseFloat(($j(window).height())/2.7)+'px'});
});
$j(window).resize(function() {
$j(".header-clear").css({'height': parseFloat(($j(window).height())/2.7)+'px'});
});
```

This got it working for me.

Comment: I can use media query in css to do this manually but wanted a sort of responsive method which would set this style for the element based on the viewport of the visitor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use the [.resize()](http://api.jquery.com/resize/) function to trigger the resize, So it would look something like this:

```
 var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

 $j(document).ready(function() {
   resizeIt();  //the first load
   $j(window).resize(function(){ resizeIt(); });  //on every resize
 });

 function resizeIt() { //function to resize your object
   $j(".header-clear").css({'height':(($j(document).height())/2.7)+'px'});
 }
```

Comment: This does not resize the div based on user viewport, it seemingly does nothing either, this is very strange to me. As I mentioned above, I can use media query in css to do this manually but wanted a sort of responsive method which would set this style for the element. I also removed 'height:400px;' from the local.css as I thought it might be overriding the .jquery but to no avail. Any other ideas?

Comment: You may want to review the link above to see how the resize() function is used, then go from there.  You're going to have to capture the window size on a resize event, then use a wrapping div or window to calculate how to set the size of the object

Comment: Thanks @Zee Tee ! I got it working using your example and the link you provided.

Answer (score 1):

Use the parseFloat as you are divided the height by 2.7 so it will the appropriate result.

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(window).load(function() {
$j(".header-clear").css({'height': parseFloat(($j(document).height())/2.7)+'px'});
});
```

Comment: it still does not resize the div based on user viewport, it seemingly does nothing, very strange to me. I can use media query in css to do this manually but wanted a sort of responsive method which would set this style for the element

Comment: Thank you MIss poo I updated the code to reflect your answer.